# Is portsentry malicious/backdoor?

Tags: unix, centos, malware

I recently figured out that a program called portsentry is listening on ports 1 and 111 on my server, but I don't remember installing it!

I wonder if it is a malicious service.

I searched through the logs and found this:

```
portsentry is not up to date (Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969)
Fetching http://httpupdate.cpanel.net/pub/sysup/9-64/portsentry/portsentry-1.1-5.x86_64.rpm (0)....@74.50.xxx.xxx......connected......receiving...100%......Done
portsentry                  ##################################################

Sep 13 06:35:47 host portsentry[4681]: adminalert: Psionic PortSentry 1.1 is starting.
Sep 13 06:35:48 host portsentry[4685]: adminalert: Going into listen mode on TCP port: 1
Sep 13 06:35:48 host portsentry[4685]: adminalert: Going into listen mode on TCP port: 111
Sep 13 06:35:48 host portsentry[4685]: adminalert: PortSentry is now active and listening.
Sep 13 06:35:48 host portsentry[4686]: adminalert: Psionic PortSentry 1.1 is starting.
Sep 13 06:35:48 host portsentry[4687]: adminalert: ERROR: No UDP ports supplied in config file. Aborting
```

I have a CentOS with CPanel...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PortSentry comes with cPanel by default and is therefore installed on your system when you have cPanel installed. If you do have cPanel installed, there's nothing to worry about.

From http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap14sec116.html:

> A port scan is a symptom of a larger
>   problem coming your way. It is often
>   the pre-cursor for an attack and is a
>   critical piece of information for
>   properly defending your information
>   resources. PortSentry is a program
>   designed to detect and respond to port
>   scans against a target host in
>   real-time and has a number of options
>   to detect port scans. When it finds
>   one it can react in the following
>   ways:
>
> A log indicating the incident is made
>   via syslog(). The target host is
>   automatically dropped into
>   /etc/hosts.deny for TCP Wrappers. The
>   local host is automatically
>   re-configured to route all traffic to
>   the target to a dead host to make the
>   target system disappear. The local
>   host is automatically re-configured to
>   drop all packets from the target via a
>   local packet filter. The purpose of
>   this is to give an admin a heads up
>   that their host is being probed.

Answer (score 2):

PortSentry is an intrusion detection system.  It can alert you or log any suspected attempts to attack your system remotely.  It might even be able to report these directly to your firewall to temporarily increase security during suspicious behavior.  It probably came with your operating system or firewall, and you should leave it running.

Comment: are you sure it comes with my CentOS? I never got any reports/notifications from it!

Comment: It looks like CPanel comes with PortSentry.  If you never got notifications before, you're probably seeing them now because it's complaining about being out-of-date.  Make sure you don't have a firewall blocking the server httpupdate.cpanel.net.  Also, check for updates for the server by running (as root) `yum update` then `yum upgrade`.  If that doesn't work, see if there is a newer version of CPanel from http://www.cpanel.net